# "Run-Time Check Failure #2: Stack around variable 'dayc' was corrupted"

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm writing a program in C that asks the user to input temperatures from one scale for 7 days, and the program will convert those temperatures to the opposite scale. Please note that I'm also supposed to write the case for when the user inputs Fahrenheit temperatures but I'm not there yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 7

float CELC(float x)
{
    float c;
    c = (x*(9.0/5.0))+32;
}

void TempConverter(void)
{
    char cmd;
    float x, b, c, dayc[N], dayf[N];
    int i;

    printf("\nHello, this program converts the temperatures of the last week from one scale to another.\n");
    printf("\nWhat is the scale of the temperature degrees you want to enter?\n");
    printf("\nPlease enter f for Fahrenheit and c for Celsius:\n\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &cmd);

    if (cmd == 'c')
    {
        for (i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter the temperature of day %d: ", i);
            scanf_s("%f", &dayc[i]);
            if (dayc[i] > 60.0 || dayc[i] < -50.0)
            {
            printf("\nThis is an invalid temperature, please enter a different value\n");
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        dayc[i] = CELC(dayc[i]);
    }

    printf("\nYour equivalent Fahrenheit temperatures are as follows:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("\nThe temperature of day %d:%f\n", i+1, dayc[i]);
    }
}
```

}

For some reason, I keep receiving the run-time error and then my temperatures that have been converted to Fahrenheit come out weird. I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with my usage of dayc but I'm not sure what to do.

[Here is a picture of my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lKQ5.png)

Comment: Note that arrays in `c` are 0-based, so you should loop from 0 to arraySize-1. `dayc` has 7 items, indexed 0 through 6, so you need to loop from 0 to `N-1`.  `dayc[7]` is out of bounds of the array and accessing it invokes undefined behavior. Also, your compiler should be giving you warning about not returning a value from your `CELC` function, don't forget to `return c;`

Comment: Thank you so much! My code is working properly now.